# Git и доступность сервера через него (безопасность)

Tags: git

Есть проект, за его разработку было заплачено. При обсуждении объёмов работы с разработчиком произошёл скандал. Разработчик меленько гадит на сервере: к примеру останавливает веб-сервер (apache2) и юзеры "не видят" сайт. Я сменил пароль root и пароль root от mysql. 
Но разработчик использовал git для работы с кодом на сервере. И эти гит-папки, файлы остались. Может ли он через них

а) Узнать текущее содержимое файлов с кодом на сервере (к примеру конфигурационного файла с параметрами БД)

б) Залить изменения на сервер, не обладая доступом к root или другой учётной записи?

в) Как-либо ещё повредить проекту?

И как исправить, если ответы утвердительные.

Спасибо!

Comment: у вас есть документальные подтверждения, что это именно его рук дело?

Comment: Я знаю его IP, я вижу историю команд в консоли, я вижу, что последний логин (совпадающий по времени с историей команд и остановкой сервера) с его IP. Чем не доказательство?

Comment: почему вопрос о том может ли он навредить проекту по средством `git` но Вы не упоминаете что у него есть доступ к серверу?

Comment: Прошу прощения, думал, что это понятно по тому, что я сменил root пароли в linux/mysql. Был неправ.

Comment: @Alex, не забудьте сменить пароли и удалить авторизованные *openssh*-ключи у всех учётных записей, под которыми можно осуществить ssh-логин на сервер.

Comment: @alexander barakin скажите, что загуглить, чтобы посмотреть, как это сделать? "удалить авторизованные openssh-ключи у всех учётных записей, под которыми можно осуществить ssh-логин на сервер" я об этом. Спасибо

Comment: @Alex, если не нашли чёткого ответа, лучше задайте **новый** вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не может. Git сам по себе не имеет и не требует каких-либо постоянно работающих сервисов под суперпользоваетлем. Соответственно, очень навряд ли указанные действия выполняются данным разработчиком посредством git - у git к этому просто нет доступа.

Упрощенно говоря, репозиторий git - просто скрытая папка с кучей служебных файлов. Для работы с ним нужно иметь права для записи/чтения содержимого этой папки. Для обеспечения более быстрого доступа может происходить запуск исполняемого файла git на сервере и проброс ввода/вывода ему от клиента.

Начните мониторинг трафика этого разработчика, дабы найти, что он реально делает для совершения указанных вами действий.

Comment: пользователь добавил в комментариях что доступ к серверу у разработчика есть

Comment: @username, ну вот видимо используя его разработчик и "гадит", а вовсе не "через git"

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но есть инструменты, что позволяют делать пулл из мастера при коммите в него.